# Python pandas parse table from website does not work

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, html-parsing

I want to extract a table from a website. So I wrote the following code which works for a German weather website:

```
import pandas as pd

df, = pd.read_html("https://www.dwd.de/DE/leistungen/beobachtung/beobachtung.html")

print(df)
```

Since I was satisfied I tried the same code to the table of the following Russian website:

```
import pandas as pd

df= pd.read_html("https://www.ifm.com/ru/ru/category/010/010_010/010_010_020#!/S/DD/DM/1/D/0/F/0/T/24")[0]

print(df)
```

But now the output looks kind of strange:

```
        {{'LABEL_PRODUCTS' | translate }}  \
        0  {{product.product.name}}  {{product.description}}        1           
    {{'ORDER_DETAIL_SUBTOTAL' | translate}}:          {{'SHOPPING_CART_QUANTITY' | 
    translate}}  \               0                     {{product.quantity}}      
                1       {{subTotal | showPrices : "true"}}                       
                        {{'LABEL_SUM' | translate}}        0
  {{product.totalPrice.formattedValue | showPric...        1   
     NaN        [Program finished]
```

Now I don't know why it cannot properly parse for the table content. Is the table too complicated or not tagged properly?

Comment: The second link puts its table together using Angular - meaning JavaScript adds / rearranges elements in the DOM, and adds data to the page. I would assume that pandas will struggle with this. What you're seeing is what is in the table before Angular parses it. You can see this in the page source.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Do I have to use other parsers than pandas?

Comment: You will struggle to parse a page using Angular as you can't just read one document, you need to actually render the page and then pull it apart, and the time until Angular has done its thing is somewhat arbitrary. I would suggest going after the JSON which supplies data to the angular directives instead. (https://www.ifm.com/restservices/ru/ru/category/categorydetails/at_produkt-markteinfuehrungsdatum/D/010_010_020?from=0&to=24) you can see this in the network tab of your inspector tool. Please, please be aware of copyright and data legal issues if you plan on using this feed.

Comment: Alright, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site is dynamic, thus, you will have to use a browser manipulation tool such as `selenium`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get('https://www.dwd.de/DE/leistungen/beobachtung/beobachtung.html')
table = soup(d.page_source, 'lxml')
headers = [i.text for i in table.find_all('th', {'scope':'col'})]
full_table = (lambda x:[x[i:i+len(headers)] for i in range(0, len(x), len(headers))])([i.text for i in table.find_all('td')])
frame = pd.DataFrame([dict(zip(headers, i)) for i in full_table])
```

Output:

```
        Böen   DD   FF   FX  HÖHE  LUFTD.  RR30               Station  TEMP.  \
0        ---  --   ---  ---     0  ------  ----            UFS TW Ems    ---   
1        ---  --   ---  ---     0  ------  ----    UFS Deutsche Bucht    ---   
2        ---   W    13   18     4  1014.2   0.0             Helgoland   
15.1   
3        ---  NW    28   41    26  1012.6   0.0             List/Sylt   
17.1   
4        ---   W    21   32    43  1012.4   0.0             Schleswig   
19.1   
5        ---  --   ---  ---     5  ------  ----       Leuchtturm Kiel    ---   
6        ---   W    23   35    27  1011.8   0.0                  Kiel   
20.9   
7        ---   W    21   24     3  1011.4   0.0               Fehmarn   
19.0   
8   Windböen   W    44   58    42  1010.0   0.0                Arkona   
18.9   
9        ---  NW    15   20    11  1014.9   0.0             Norderney   
16.4   
10       ---  --   ---  ---    32  ------  ----   Leuchtt. Alte Weser    ---   
11       ---  NW    19   30     5  1014.1   0.0              Cuxhaven   
16.8   
12       ---   W    18   28    11  1013.3   0.0          Hamburg-Flh.   
17.4   
13       ---   W    14   27    59  1012.3   0.0              Schwerin   
17.9   
14       ---   W    20   30     4  1011.4   0.0               Rostock   
19.7   
15       ---   W    21   33     2  1010.8   0.0            Greifswald
....
[79 rows x 11 columns]
```

Comment: Okay, sorry for the delay, now I had time to test it. It indeed works for the German weather-site. But there all 'th'-elements have a proper title.

If I use it for the Russian website however, it only produces some of the correct words and many \n for the headers. So I dont know, whats wrong with this site. 

The output for the headers gives:
['Продукция', 'Количество', 'Сумма', '', 'Прибор', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n', '\n']

Why doesn't it work with this website?

Comment: I found out, that "table = soup(d.page_source, 'lxml')" does not return "th" entries with the full information. Maybe the soup has to act differently on the website somehow...

Comment: I think I found the error. The Browser simulation does not find all headers, because the browser needs about 3 seconds to completely load the page. Inserting a time.sleep(5) before looking for the table with soup solved the issue, thanks alot!

Comment: @Martin Apologies for the late response! I am glad you found the solution. Thank you for letting me know about it.